# "By the river" vs "at the river."

Tags: grammar, word-choice, prepositions

Which one is more common?

Example sentence:

> The firework festival was held **at/by** the river.

Or are they equally correct?

Comment: Both are fine. Perhaps because it''s a specific ***event*** that should therefore take place at a specific ***location***, I might be more inclined to use ***at*** - particularly if there was a known spot on the riverside often used for such public gatherings. But I might say *Let's have our picnic **by** the river* even if the exact spot I had in mind was the same as the place I'd referenced using ***at*** when talking about where the festival was held last month. One preposition focuses more on *locating / finding* the place, the other is more about *describing what's in the vicinity*.

Comment: _At the river_ is rather archaic/poetic (as in the old American hymn 'Shall we gather at the river?'). _By the river_ is more idiomatic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"by the river" would be apt.

"by some place" suggests next to, near or beside a place.So by the river would be a better choice

"at the river".Well, I have noticed "at" being used with river in few cases but as per my limited knowledge, "at" is generally used for specific locations or points in space.Since river is too big to be encapsulated in a specific space, I believe "by the river" is more apt.

Answer (score 1):

If the firework festival was being held on a barge moored on the river you would say *on the river*. If it is being held on a piece of land next to the river you would say *by the river* or *beside the river*. If you say *at the river* people would understand you of course but it is not the most common preposition for an event y the river.